# Divide the row categories in a column by values for same category but on different date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data set with millions of rows, and about 400 categories. Each category contains weekly data from year 2019, 2020 and 2021. I am trying to normalize a column value by dividing its  weekly value by the corresponding week value for year 2019. The column contains data from different category.

The sample data is like this[:](https://i.stack.imgur.com)

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra24s.jpg)/m25c4.png

I will like to get output like this:
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM5di.jpg)

I tried using python to do that but its taking hours to run.
My code is something like this

```
for category, weeks in category_weeks_dict.items():
    for week in weeks:
        y = df.query("category== @category and Year==2019 and week==@week['value'].values
        if not y: y=np.nan
        df.loc[(df['category']==category) & (df['week']==week), 'value'] = y
```

The code basically create a new column and assign the 2019 values for each category and week. So that i can then divide the value column by the 2019 value column.
So i created a dict containing each category and their unique weeks {A:[1,2,3,4], B:[1,2,3,4]...}. and then get y which is the 2019 value for each category and week.

Is there a better way I can do this with pandas. I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If all years have the same categories and weeks

If the dataframe is sorted as in your sample, such that the number and order of weeks and categories is exactly repeated for each year, then you can vectorize the calculation, which should be much faster.

Use [`np.tile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to create an array that contains the values from 2019, repeated as many times as you have years (2 in the sample data), so that this array has the same length as the whole dataframe. Then you can calculate the normalized values by dividing the values column by this array, which will be done element-wise.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
                                'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
                                'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'year': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
                            2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020,
                            2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020],
                   'val': [100, 200, 300, 400, 300, 200, 500, 700,
                           450, 550, 650, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100,
                           100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
                   'week': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                            1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                            1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

val_2019 = np.tile(df.val[df.year == 2019], 2)
df['normalized'] = df.val / val_2019

df
```

```
    category  year  val     week  normalized
0   A         2019  100     1     1.000000
1   A         2019  200     2     1.000000
2   A         2019  300     3     1.000000
3   A         2019  400     4     1.000000
4   B         2019  300     1     1.000000
5   B         2019  200     2     1.000000
6   B         2019  500     3     1.000000
7   B         2019  700     4     1.000000
8   C         2019  450     1     1.000000
9   C         2019  550     2     1.000000
10  C         2019  650     3     1.000000
11  C         2019  200     4     1.000000
12  A         2020  100     1     1.000000
13  A         2020  100     2     0.500000
14  A         2020  100     3     0.333333
15  A         2020  100     4     0.250000
16  B         2020  100     1     0.333333
17  B         2020  100     2     0.500000
18  B         2020  100     3     0.200000
19  B         2020  100     4     0.142857
20  C         2020  100     1     0.222222
21  C         2020  100     2     0.181818
22  C         2020  100     3     0.153846
23  C         2020  100     4     0.500000
```

Note that I renamed the `values` column, to avoid mistakes, because `df.values` is a dataframe attribute, containing the values from all columns.

### If the years may have different categories and weeks

I've changed the example data below to illustrate this case.
To make the vectorized approach work anyway, you have to align the same categories and weeks for each year. This can be done by transforming the dataframe to a wide format:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 
                                'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C',
                                'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                   'year': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
                            2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020,
                            2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
                   'val': [100, 200, 300, 400, 300, 200, 500, 700, 350,
                           200, 400, 600, 200, 300, 100, 100, 700, 700,
                           100, 200, 200, 600, 350],
                   'week': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
                            1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
                            1, 2, 1, 2, 1]})

df_wide = df.pivot(index='year', columns=['category', 'week'], values='val')
df_wide
```

```
category A                      B                       C
week     1      2       3       1       2       3       1       2       3
year                                    
2019     100.0  200.0   300.0   400.0   300.0   200.0   500.0   700.0   350.0
2020     200.0  400.0   600.0   200.0   300.0   100.0   100.0   700.0   700.0
2021     100.0  200.0   NaN     200.0   600.0   NaN     350.0   NaN     NaN
```

Now you can divide every value by the corresponding 2019 value, making use of NumPy's broadcasting rules:

```py
df_norm = df_wide / df_wide.loc[2019]
df_norm
```

```
category A                      B                       C
week     1      2       3       1       2       3       1       2       3
year                                    
2019     1.0    1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
2020     2.0    2.0     2.0     0.5     1.0     0.5     0.2     1.0     2.0
2021     1.0    1.0     NaN     0.5     2.0     NaN     0.7     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Arne. But some category may have year up to 2022 while some could be up to 2021 or less. Also, in a year, some category make have sparse number of weeks in one year while the other year will be up to 52 weeks. Is there another way i can address this? Thank you!

Comment: To be able to use the np.tile, i am considering filling up missing val with nan. E.g if category A has 4 wks value for 2019 and has only 3wks value for 2020. I want to add the extra wk and then fill its value with nan. Pls how do i do this?

Comment: I've added the more irregular case to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I found the np.tile very helpful. I had to restructure my data to use it, and it was very fast.